# fitting generalised additive model in oohbchoice

Tags: dataframe

How can i fit a generalised additive model in OOHBchoice oohb1>-oohbchoice(R1 + R2 ~ age + gender | log(BL) + log(BH), data = oohbsyn)

I tried but it brought an error Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) :
cannot coerce class ‘c("oohbchoice", "dbchoice")’ to a data.frame